# Telegram meteor bot

Tags: javascript, telegram-bot, telegram, meteor

Использую библиотеку [meteor-telegram-bot](https://github.com/benjick/meteor-telegram-bot).
Сейчас я от бота получаю только текст вот таким вот кодом:

```
TelegramBot.setCatchAllText(true, function(username, message) { 
TelegramBot.send("Markdown-flavored Message:\n" + message.text, message.chat.id, true); });
```

Нашёл код, но он принимает документ, а мне нужно, чтобы он принимал фото и плюс текст, который пользователь напишет.

Код принятия файла:

```
TelegramBot.addListener('incoming_document', function(c, u, o) {
    TelegramBot.send('Got a file with ID ' + o.document.file_id, o.chat.id);
    var file = TelegramBot.method('getFile', {
        file_id: o.document.file_id
    }).result.file_path;
    TelegramBot.send('Download the file at https://api.telegram.org/file/bot' + TelegramBot.token + '/' + file, o.chat.id);
}, 'document');
```

А мне нужно именно фото.

Comment: Где у вас возникли затруднения? Добавте в вопрос код.

Comment: Сейчас я от бота получаю только текст, вот таким вот кодом: TelegramBot.setCatchAllText(true, function(username, message) {
    TelegramBot.send("Markdown-flavored Message:\n" + message.text, message.chat.id, true);
});

Comment: Как сделать так, чтобы получать не только текст, но ещё и картинку вместе с этим текстом?

Comment: Нашёл вот код, но он принимает документ, а мне нужно, чтобы он получал фото от него и плюс текст, который пользователь напишет. Вот код:TelegramBot.addListener('incoming_document', function(c, u, o) {
 TelegramBot.send('Got a file with ID ' + o.document.file_id, o.chat.id);
 var file = TelegramBot.method('getFile', {
  file_id: o.document.file_id
 }).result.file_path;
 // Don't do this in production because it will expose your Telegram Bot's API key
 TelegramBot.send('Download the file at https://api.telegram.org/file/bot' + TelegramBot.token + '/' + file, o.chat.id);
}, 'document');

Comment: Переместите код в тело вопроса кнопкой [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/720543/edit).

Comment: Не могу добавить, пишу с телефона, весь код есть там в примерах, я только его использую и все

Comment: Я тоже на телефоне, может кто заметит и сделает правку.

Comment: А мы можем пообщаться через пару часов, я до компа доеду

Comment: Я не совсем понял, какое отличие документа от фото?

Comment: Отличие в том, что к фото можно добавлять текст, а к документу нельзя, поэтому и нужно именно фото с добавленным к нему текстом